# calculating an infinte sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

given that : $\alpha_{i}$ = $\frac1{2^{i+1}}$  and  $\beta_{i}$ = (1+$\frac{{(i-1)i}}{2} +(2i))$ 2

How can we calculate this infinite  sum :

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{ \alpha_{i}\beta_{i}}$$

I calculate 1200 terms of this sum using python , and it is seems that it converges to 8 .

How can we proove that mathematically ?

This was my try :

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{ \alpha_{i}\beta_{i}}$$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{ \left(\frac1{2^{i}} + \frac{{(i-1)}i}{2^{i+1} } + \frac{{2}i}{2^{i} }\right)}$$

The first term is easy ( geometric serie ), but what the second and the third term ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? (mathematically, not numerically)

Comment: There's something wrong in your MathJax representation in your given... is that supposed to be: $$\beta_i = \left(1+\frac{(1+i)i}{2} + 2i \right)$$ Or is that last 2 also part of the equation? Either way, your initial presentation doesn't quite fit with your calculation at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry , i made a mistake , it is corrected now !

Comment: OK, I still feel like there's a disconnect between the first thing you posted and the multiplcation at the bottom; I'll assume the bottom sum is the correct one.

Comment: yes the bottom sum is what i looking for , actually they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to indicate from your question that you understand how to calculate the first term. As you mentioned, it's a geometric series, the formula for which is well known. The last term is a little more complicated. It's an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). The formulas for these are known, and can be found in the linked article:

$$\Sigma i(r)^i = \frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}$$

So for $r = \frac12$ we have:

$$\Sigma i(\frac12)^i = \frac{\frac12}{(\frac12)^2} = \frac{\frac12}{(\frac14)} = 2$$

The middle term is yet again slightly more complicated. Let's work out a general formula first that'll help us. Suppose we want to calculate the infinite sum $S$ given below:

$$S = \Sigma i^2r^i$$

Assume that $r$ is such that the sum converges. Then we have can algebraically manipulate it to get an identity as follows:

$$S(1 - r) = S - rS = \Sigma i^2r^i - \Sigma i^2r^{i+1} = \\
\Sigma i^2r^i - \Sigma (i - 1)^2r^i = \\
\Sigma i^2r^i - (i - 1)^2r^i = \Sigma (2i - 1)r^i = \\
2\Sigma ir^i - \Sigma r^i$$

Now we've reduced to terms we already know: a geometric series plus an arithmetico-geometric series. Applying the formulas we've already seen for those:

$$ = 2\left(\frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}\right) - \frac{r}{1 - r}$$

Remember this is the term for $S(1 - r)$ so to get $S$ we divide by $1 - r$ to get:

$$S = 2\left(\frac{r}{(1 - r)^3}\right) - \frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}$$

In particular, when $r = \frac12$ then $S$ is:

$$S = 2\left(\frac{\frac12}{(\frac12)^3}\right) - \frac{\frac12}{( \frac12)^2} = \\
2\left(\frac{\frac12}{(\frac18)}\right) - \frac{\frac12}{(\frac14)} = \\
2(\frac82) - \frac42 = 8 - 2 = 6$$

You now have mathematical formulae for all the terms in your expression. Let's plug them into your expression and just use some algebra/rearrangement of sums to work out the result. First, though, I think your formula is slightly incorrect. You have:

$$\sum{ \left(\frac1{2^{i}} + \frac{{(i-1)}i}{2^{i+1} } + \frac{{2}i}{2^{i} }\right)}$$

But I believe you should start with:

$$\sum{ \left(\frac2{2^{i}} + \frac{{(i-1)}i}{2^{i+1} } + \frac{{2}i}{2^{i} }\right)}$$

Notice the $2$ multiplier on the first term, which I think you forgot. From here, you can derive your convergence to $8$:

$$\sum{ \left(\frac2{2^{i}} + \frac{{(i-1)}i}{2^{i+1} } + \frac{{2}i}{2^{i} }\right)} = \\
2\sum\frac{1}{2^{i}} + \sum\frac{{(i-1)}i}{2^{i+1} } + \sum\frac{{2}i}{2^{i} } = \\ 2(1) + \sum\frac{i^2}{2^{i+1} } - \sum\frac{i}{2^{i+1} } + 2\sum\frac{i}{2^{i} }
= \\ 2 + \frac12\sum\frac{i^2}{2^i } - \frac12\sum\frac{i}{2^i} + 2\sum\frac{i}{2^{i} }
= \\ 2 + \frac12\sum\frac{i^2}{2^i } + \frac32\sum\frac{i}{2^{i} } \\
= \\ 2 + \frac12\sum i^2(\frac{1}{2})^i + \frac32\sum i(\frac{1}{2})^i \\
= \\ 2 + \frac12(6) + \frac32(2) = \\
2 + 3 + 3 = 8$$

Comment: Nice reasoning , but we still have to proove that $\Sigma\frac{i^2}{2^{i}} = 24$

Comment: Are you sure that $\Sigma\frac{1}{2^{i}}$ = 1 ?

Comment: @meh98 Your second question there is the first geometric series almost everyone learns, so yes, you can be sure of that summing to 1. And the proof for $\sum \frac{i^2}{2^i}$ is in the answer.

Comment: @Colm Bhandal  I'd never seen that sort of conversion for the squared infinite sum. That's wonderfully tidy, I love it.

Comment: @EricSnyder I read a bunch of research papers and they were beyond me. They give the result in full generality, for any power (squared, cubed, you name it), and then some (there are other variables in the generalisation that I didn't understand). But what I did take away is this: if you have a formula for $i^kr^i$ then you can always derive a closed form formula for $i^{k+1}r^i$: just do the trick of multiplying by $(1 - r)$ and apply the binomial theorem! Of course, those formulas become increasingly complex but they're always closed form (I think).